# Error with fit_transform in scikit learn for a movie reccommender system

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the full code that I have tried to run.
It runs all well but there is error in the 2nd line from the bottom 
`count_matrix = count.fit_transform(df['bag_of_words'])`
I also don't know where this `bag_of_word` comes from..Please suggest Code Edit..

```py
import pandas as pd
from rake_nltk import Rake
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/uikepcpffyo2nhig52xxeevdialfl7')

df = df[['Title','Genre','Director','Actors','Plot']]
df.head()

 # initializing the new column
 df['Key_words'] = ""

 for index, row in df.iterrows():
    plot = row['Plot']
    r = Rake()
    r.extract_keywords_from_text(plot)
    key_words_dict_scores = r.get_word_degrees()
    row['Key_words'] = list(key_words_dict_scores.keys())
    df.drop(columns = ['Plot'], inplace = True)
    count = CountVectorizer()
    count_matrix = count.fit_transform(df['bag_of_words'])
    cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(count_matrix, count_matrix)
```

The error is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'bag_of_words'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "movie2.py", line 36, in <module>
    count_matrix = count.fit_transform(df['bag_of_words'])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'bag_of_words'
```

Please tell me what to do?

Comment: if possible share complete to replicate issue

Comment: Please not only add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but also edit you question and use some formatting. Maybe have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That means your `dataframe` does not contain `column name` as `bag_of_words`. Please try `df.head()` and check the column.

Comment: Try
`df = df[['Title','Genre','Director','Actors','Plot','bag_of_words']]` if csv contains this col. then it should work.